# Is "fugazi" (sp?) a real Italian word?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary

In "The Wolf of Wall Street" (2013), Matthew Mcconaughey's character refers to the stock market as "all a fugazi (sp?)", going on to explain in various ways that it basically means "fake" or "a sham". The scene in question is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfetinoFlKw) (**warning: contains a lot of not-work-safe language & content**), and he says the word at about 2:05.

I tried to look up this word and ran it through various Italian translators but I cannot find any reference to it anywhere. I tried manipulating the exact spelling with no luck. I only got results for some rock band and a quasi-official English military acronym.

So is this really an Italian word? Or maybe a mispronunciation or misunderstanding of one? I could imagine that it could be a quirk of Mcconaughey's character to just make up foreign words, since it would fit pretty well with what he is all about. Something about the word just really sticks with me though, like it sounds like it means exactly what he claims it does, but maybe that's just due to having seen the film.

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!

Comment: Not sure why you are asking it here... Does the character say that it is an Italian word?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nothing in it seem to have to do with Italian language. “Fugazi” isn't an Italian word, nor anything in the quoted movie implies that it is.

Comment: @DaG The question "is qpdjvinfp an Italian word?" is about Italian language, in my view. It's not the fact that the answer is "no" that makes it off-topic.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I see your point, but there is no reason at all why it should be Italian. I'd happily admit a question about a word said to be Italian by a film or a book, even if wrongly so (like “Va' fa' Napoli” from _Friends_, or what it was), or if the OP's searches could let them think it was Italian. But nothing in the film has to do with Italian, the OP explicitly says that “various Italian translators” gave no results, hence why especially Italian and not Spanish, German or something else?

Comment: @DaG Because many other similar-sounding English loanwords come from Italian. This is a sufficient reason to make it a reasonable question to ask, in my view. And, as a reasonable question that is about Italian language, I see no valid motivation not to welcome it on this site.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: “Many” similar-sounding ones? For instance? Personally, I find “fugazi” more Japanese-sounding, say, or from some Native American language than even anything European. (But I wouldn't dream of asking about it in a site about Japanese language unless some clue, albeit vague, pointed me in that direction.)

Comment: @DaG Some examples of words of Italian origin in use in English that I find similar-sounding: Paparazzi. Regatta. Fianchetto. Influenza. Pizza. Pistachio. Mozzarella. Cadenza. Fortissimo. Also, the surname of Italo-American writer Mario Puzo. The sounds seem all there (although I agree that Native American and Japanese have similar features).

Comment: @DaG Anyhow, I find little point in questioning how OP could have come to the conclusion that this word sounds Italian. The fact that it was asked (in good faith), to me, seems sufficient proof that this question is not too unthinkable.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I never questioned “how” the OP came to their conclusion, nor their good faith. I just remarked that they already had checked Italian translations with no result, so nothing would point to Italian. If the “good faith” criterion were a thing, we wouldn't need downvotes, closures, deletions and so on. Besides a small number of spammers and jokesters, the usefulness of the system is exactly for errors, duplicates, misplacements and so on, all of which are in good faith. This said, we have moderators, and apparently in their opinion this question is ok, so it's fine with me.

Comment: Apparently I started quite a discussion on this. I do realize now that there is indeed no indication that the word comes from Italian. I guess I just assumed so due to how it was pronounced, as well as the prominence of Italian characters in many of Martin Scorese's movies (although admittedly not so much in this one). This is obviously conjecture but I think it may be reasonable that many others have probably made a similar assumption.

Comment: Johnny Depp used the term "Fugazi" to describe a fake diamond in the 1997 movie Donnie Brasco. Depp portrayed Agent Joe Pistone infiltrating one of the NYC families.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an Italian word, but looking for a meaning it turned out the term was used as a name for a rock band, [Fugazi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugazi).

Investigating more about the origin of this name, it seems they chose the word "fugazi" from Mark Baker's [Nam](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0425101444), a compilation of stories of Vietnam War veterans, it there being a slang acronym for "Fucked Up, Got Ambushed, Zipped In [into a body bag].

Moreover [this site](http://www.bandnameexplained.com/2015/06/fugazi-band-name-meaning.html) tries to give an explanation about band's name:

> Band member Ian MacKaye says the name was derived from the book Nam,
> written by Mark Baker. In that book the author describes a situation
> that was typified by a Vietnam veteran as Fugazi.
>
> Fugazi is an acronym that would stand for Fucked Up, Got Ambushed,
> Zipped In.
>
> According to military sources however this explanation is completely
> off the mark and a mix up is assumed with Fubar (Fucked Up Beyond All
> Recognition).
>
> Fugazi also seems to be American/Italian slang for 'fake'

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess the main takeaway is that it is most likely American-Italian slang, which is why it make not appear in more "official" translators or dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, it is not an Italian word. Its [Wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=fugazi) lists it as an (exclusively) English word of unclear origin; some the suggested etymologies involve Italian (but personally I don't find them very convincing).

> #### Etymology 1
>
> Origin unknown; a number of possibilities have been suggested:[1]
>
> - A corruption of French *fougasse* (“type of land mine”); flame fougasses were used extensively in the Korean and Vietnam Wars.
> - An acronym of “fucked up, got ambushed, zipped in [a body bag]” (compare *FUBAR*), but this may be a backronym.
> - Less plausibly, from English fugacious (“fleeting”) or cognates such as Italian fugace (“fleeting”).
>
> #### Etymology 2
>
> Origin uncertain; said to be of Mafia origin, from the Fugazy Continental limousine company in New York City which was owned by William “Bill” Fugazy, due to its cheesy “look like a rich guy” advertisements of the 1970s and 1980s, or its alleged poor business practices,[1] possibly influenced by Italian *fu cazzo* (“it was shit”). The word was popularized by the film Donnie Brasco (1997), based on the book Donnie Brasco: My Undercover Life in the Mafia (1987) by American former FBI agent Joseph D. Pistone (born 1939) who used the name “Donnie Brasco” as an undercover alias.

Answer (score 1):

Not an Italian word: first time I've heard it in my country was as the title of a Marillion album in the early eighties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Italian and I confirm there's no such a word in our language.
It sounds a bit like "fugace" = "fleeting", but it is certainly not the meaning intended by the character of McConaughey.

Answer (score 0):

Fugazi is indeed an Italian word. It comes from Luigi V. Fugazzi (he also spelled his name as Fugazy), who was an Italian American banker, businessman, and philanthropist who became one of the most prominent "padroni" in the United States. Look it up.

Comment: “Fugazi” is certainly not an Italian word; you won't find it in any Italian dictionary. That said, do you have a source about this Mr Fugazzi being referenced in that dialogue from *The Wolf of Wall Street*?

Comment: Reading biographical data about Mr Fugazy, it seems a bit of a stretch to assume that “fugazi” can refer to sham or fake. Maybe it's slang in the aggressive financial circles, but this doesn't make the word Italian.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.se! Rather than writing "look it up", please provide a link yourself. It's much more efficient than having every single reader run a Google search on their own, and look through the results trying to figure out which among the results are the ones you meant.

Answer (score -1):

It's Italian American slang, not proper Italian. I believe it is a misuse of *fugace*. Like calling a child a rug rat. Two words that have nothing to do with children but there you go. So *fugace* means *fleeting*, and you could loosely connect *fleeting* with *fake*.